# Add subfolder to URL when passing through specific httpd server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, gitlab

I want to run a rails webapp (GitLab) in a subfolder, like `http://localhost/gitlab`, and I want to use Apache `httpd` to perform this. Some apache conf for GitLab are available [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab.conf) and they work well when I use them in a simple context.

But now I try to include this conf in a more complicated Apache conf. I have the following Apache HTTPD config:

**Front main http serveur:**

```
ServerName localhost
Listen 80
...
(lot of rules)
...
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

**2nd server**, where I have the apache conf for Gitlab and where I **try** to rewrite URL to add `/gitlab/` in the URL :

```
Listen 8888
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gitlab/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gitlab/$1
....
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  ServerName gitlab
  ServerSignature Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/.../public

</VirtualHost>
```

And finaly I have the GitLab's `unicorn` http server running at `127.0.0.1:3000`.

---

**The problem :**
When with a browser I go to `localhost:80/gitlab` it works: I can access the GitLab homepage. But all html links on this page lead me to `localhost:80/somewhere` and not to `localhost:80/gitlab/somewhere`.

So here is my question: how can I (in my 2nd httpd instance, running on `8888`) **force** the add of `/gitlab/` in the URL for each query passing though this server ? I tried some `RewriteRule` in the conf, but they didn't change any URL.

(Also, for some reasons I don't want to use the Rails config `relative_url_root: /gitlab` param to achieve this: it does not make GitLab run in a subdirectory, it just create a redirection from `/` to `/gitlab/`.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is exactly what you said you don't want to do. Make gitlab run in a subdirectory at `/gitlab/` from unicorn. That would make Gitlab write the HTML links the correct way the first time so Apache doesn't have to modify anything as it passes through.

The problem you're running into is having Apache rewrite the actual HTML to add `/gitlab/` to the URL as it passes through. That is no easy task for a HTTP server. For Apache, you may want to look into the [`mod_proxy_html` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) to accomplish this. Granted, it may not be a perfect solution.

Comment: Thx for you answer Steven. I'll take a look at `mod_proxy_html`. And as you said, the easiest way is to have the `/gitlab/` from unicorn, but it the GitLab case it fails and it just create a redirection. Look this output : http://pastebin.com/rFg9LaRw

Comment: @metaDiego you'll also need to update the `config/gitlab.yml` and uncomment the `relative_url_root` configuration option.

Comment: Yes I already done this. I changed all the config files mentioned at the end of `gitlab-rails/config/application.rb`, there are 4 if I remember well